# google drive integration with meteor

Tags: meteor, google-api

I need my meteor application to access users google spreadsheets and read them. Does meteor auth have such functionality ? Do I need to use google-apis-nodejs-client module and integrate it with meteor app?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor doesn't have this functionality. A package might add this functionality. Using an npm package is also a good option.

The meteor accounts system allows you to sign with a Google account, but has nothing to do with Google drive or editing spreadsheets.